# How to protect API keys in client side libraries

Tags: javascript, api

I'm writing a client side library for an API I've developed and I want to allow users of the API to be able to use it without letting other people steal their access to the API.

I've seen many online services (Facebook, Google, etc.) do similar things and wanted to know what the best practices are for designing something like this securely.

Comment: With services like Facebook and Google what you're actually doing is authenticating with the API on behalf of a user, using something like [OAuth](http://oauth.net/2/). You can't protect any endpoint with a single password, token or whatever you want to call it because as you know it's always viewable by the client. You're pretty much stuck putting any code that interacts with your API on the server and having that proxy requests for data from your API.

Comment: @Marty So for each visitor to a web page that needs to communicate with the API I need to setup some kind of session for them?